# Calculate sum for column in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, output

I need to get sum of positive values as one value and sum of negative values as one values of a column in dataframe.
for eg:-

```
date       |  amount
2021-09-02 | 98.3
2021-08-25 |  -23.4
2021-08-14 | 34.57
2021-07-30 | -87.9
```

then i need (98.3+34.57) and (-23.4-87.9) as output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) with `sum`:

```
pos = df['amount'].clip(lower=0).sum()
neg = df['amount'].clip(upper=0).sum()
print (pos)
132.87
print (neg)
-111.3
```

Or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `sum` and filtering with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater, `~` is used for invert mask for negative values:

```
m = df["amount"].gt(0)
pos = df.loc[m, "amount"].sum()
neg = df.loc[~m, "amount"].sum()
print (pos)
132.87
print (neg)
-111.3
```

Answer (score 4):

You could select your values based on the greater/lower than zero condition:

```
df.loc[df["amount"] > 0, "amount"].sum()  # sum of greater than 0
df.loc[df["amount"] < 0, "amount"].sum()  # sum of lower than 0
```

In each line you're using `.loc` to first select the rows where the value is positive/negative, and then selecting the "amount" column. Finally, we're adding those values using `.sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to compute both sums in one shot is to define a group, this avoids having to read twice the dataset during the summation:

```
import numpy as np
out = df['amount'].groupby(np.where(df['amount'].ge(0), 'Positive', 'Negative')).sum()
```

output:

```
Negative   -111.30
Positive    132.87
```